# round number to nearest tenth using calc

Tags: calc

I'm trying to use the below code to get 0,1,2,...,5 but I'm getting 0.59999,0.79999,0.9999. How is it possible to fix it

```
\foreach \i [] in {0,0.2,...,1}{
    \draw (0,{5*\i}) --++(-0.2,0) node[left]{$\i$};
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you discovered, PGF floating point arithmetic is not that good. It's sufficient for typesetting purposes, but not generally.

Integer arithmetic is better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [] in {0,1,...,5}{
  \draw (0,{\i}) -- +(-0.2,0) node[left]{\fpeval{\i/5}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Note that I used `\fpeval` (available with recent LaTeX versions, otherwise add `\usepackage{xfp}`).

[image]

For other rounding cases, you can use

```
\fpeval{round(<floating point number>,<number of decimal digits>)}
```

in your case it would be `\fpeval{round(\i/5,1)}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i [] in {0,0.2,...,1}{
\draw (0,{5*\i}) -- +(-0.2,0) node[left]{\pgfmathprintnumber{\i}};
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Vertical number line]